# how to add brackets around numbers and assignment operator after numbers

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with ~1000 rows
here is the first few rows:

```
head file.regions.txt
cregions1
cregions2
cregions3
cregions4
cregions5
cregions6
cregions7
cregions8
cregions9
cregions10
...
```

I want to add brackets around the numbers and also "<-" for each row after numbers!
This is my desired output

```
head file.regions.output.txt
    cregions[1] <-
    cregions[2] <-
    cregions[3] <-
    cregions[4] <-
    cregions[5] <-
    cregions[6] <-
    cregions[7] <-
    cregions[8] <-
    cregions[9] <-
    cregions[10] <-
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
sed -e 's/$/] <-/g' -e 's/cregions/cregions[/g' yourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```bash
sed -r 's/^(cregions)([0-9]+)$/\1[\2] <-/' file.regions.txt >file.regions.output.txt
```

Note that this doesn't add any leading tabs or spaces. (You didn't mention that in your problem description, but your output example seems to have them.)

This only changes lines whose entire contents is `cregionsN`, with one or more digits in place of ***`N`***. If you want to apply the transformation to *any* line that ends in one or more digits, you can use this simpler `sed` command instead:

```bash
sed -r 's/[0-9]+$/[&] <-/' file.regions.txt >file.regions.output.txt
```

(Thanks [to glenn jackman for pointing out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525698/how-to-add-brackets-around-numbers-and-assignment-operator-after-numbers/525700?noredirect=1#comment972801_525700) that this version of the command does not need capture groups because it can simply use `&`, which represents the entire match.)

With either of these commands, you can of course see the output instead of writing it to a file by omitting the `>file.regions.output.txt` redirection.

Comment: You don't need to capture: `sed -r 's/[0-9]+$/[&] <-/'` -- the `&` in the replacement side is replaced by all the text that was matched.